# User sessions and logins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to implement signup & login features on ROR. on Index page i have created 2 links saying 'new user' and 'login' and in userscontroller i have signup & login methods(updated routes accordingly).

prob: upon clicking new user or login i am getting an error saying

"The action 'show' could not be found for UsersController"

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :users

get 'users/register', :to=>'users#register'
get 'users/signup', :to=>'users#signup'
post 'users/signup', :to=>'users#signup'
post 'users/login', :to=>'users#login'
get 'users/login', :to=>'users#login'
post "users/change_password" => "users#change_password"
get "users/change_password" => "users#change_password"
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "New User", users_register_path %><br>
<%= link_to "Login", users_login_path %><br>
<%= link_to "Change Password", users_change_password_path %><br>
```

userscontroller:

```
def index
  @user_details = User.all
end

def register
  puts "**********************"
  puts params
  @new_user = User.new
end

def signup
  @new_user = User.new(user_register)
  if @new_user.save
  session[:user] = User.authenticate(@user.name,@user.password)
  redirect_to :action=>"welcome"
 else
   redirect_to :action=>"login"
 end
end

def login
  puts params
  if request.post?
  session[:user] = User.authenticate(params[:user][:name],   params[:user][:password])
   redirect_to :action=>"welcome"
  else
  #  redirect_to :action=>"signup"
 end
end



 def change_password

   puts "**********************"
   puts params
   puts "**********************"

  if request.post?
  @pass_change = User.new_password(params[:user][:name], params[:user][:password], params[:user][:new_password])
 end
end

def welcome
 end


 def user_register
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:password_confirmation)
 end

 end
```

usermodel.rb:

```
require 'digest/sha1'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base


 attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation

 def password=(pass)
    @password = pass

   self.salt = User.random_met(10)
   self.hashedpassword = User.encrypt(@password, self.salt)
 end

  def self.encrypt(pass,salt)
     Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(pass+salt)
  end

  def self.authenticate(login, pass)
    user_auth = User.find(:first, :conditions=>["login = ?", login])
    return nil if user_auth.nil?
    return user_auth if     User.encrypt(pass,user_auth.salt)==user_auth.hashedpassword
  end


   def self.new_password(name,old,new)
      user = where(:name=>name)
      #puts user.email

     # how to call setter(password) method from here. because   My idea is
     #if User.encrypt(old, user.salt)==user.hashedpassword
     # run def password=(pass), thereby storing new password.
    end

  def self.random_met(len)
     char = ("a".."z").to_a + ("A".."Z").to_a + ("0".."9").to_a
     salted = ""
      1.upto(len) { |i| salted << char[rand(char.size-1)] }
    return salted
   end

  end
```

Comment: On clicking on which `link` results an `error`?

Comment: all links. new user, login

Comment: Try removing `resources :users` at the top and add it in the last  in your `routes.rb`

Comment: thanks. its working . can u tell me whats the problem

Comment: I will explain it in my answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the [**Guides**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html),

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

You have defined **`resources :users`** above the **`get routes`**, so the rails will look for a **`show route`**, so is the **error**.